# Using For loop in python to make it grammatically correct

Tags: python, string-formatting

A gymnast can earn a score between 1 and 10 from each judge; nothing lower, nothing higher. All scores are integer values; there are no decimal scores from a single judge. Store the possible scores a gymnast can earn from one judge in a tuple. Print out the sentence:

> "The lowest possible score is ____, and the highest possible score is
>   ____."

Use the values from your tuple. Print out a series of sentences, "A judge can give a gymnast _ points."

My Solution:

```
scores = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

for num in scores:
    print('A judge can give a gymnast %d points.' % (num))
```

Output:

```
A judge can give a gymnast 1 points.  
A judge can give a gymnast 2 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 3 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 4 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 5 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 6 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 7 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 8 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 9 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 10 points.
```

How can I change the first line so that it becomes grammatically correct "A judge can give a gymnast 1 point"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals) from python 3.6:

```
scores = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

for num in scores:
    print(f'A judge can give a gymnast {num} point{"s" if num > 1 else ""}.')
```

Output:

```
A judge can give a gymnast 1 point.
A judge can give a gymnast 2 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 3 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 4 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 5 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 6 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 7 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 8 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 9 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 10 points.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional expression to only add the `'s'` to `'point'` if the number is greater than `1`. Also note that using `range()` is neater than manually typing the scores and `.format` better than a `%` (especially when doing multiple formats).

```
for num in range(1, 11):
    print('A judge can give a gymnast {} point{}.'.format(num, 's' if num > 1 else ''))
```

which gives:

```
A judge can give a gymnast 1 point.
A judge can give a gymnast 2 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 3 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 4 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 5 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 6 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 7 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 8 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 9 points.
A judge can give a gymnast 10 points.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)